# How does this algorithm that multiplies $(1 + x)(1 + x^2)(1 + x^3)(1 + x^4)...$ work?

Tags: polynomials, computer-science, computational-complexity

To multiply polynomials (using a computer) you presented that polynomial as a `list` or `array` where the value of a position corresponds to the coefficient of that variable and the index of the position corresponds to the power of that variable.

For example $1+0x+x^2+0x^3+5x^4$ will be represented as $[1, 0, 1, 0, 5]$ and so on.

In a particular case, I had to build an algorithm that multiplies the following:

$(1 + x)(1 + x^2)(1 + x^3)(1 + x^4)...$

I use a function that uses a nested `for loop` to multiply two polynomials and I call that function on each of the terms in the above expression using another `for loop`.

That ends up giving a time-complexity of $O(n^3)$ to the algorithm.

However, I saw an algorithm that does the same thing in the time-complexity of $O(n^2)$ and I am not sure if it is specific to the

$(1 + x)(1 + x^2)(1 + x^3)(1 + x^4)...$

series or not?

For example, if I want to find up to the $x^{10}$ then I create an `array` with $10 + 1$ zeros which starts with $1$.

Then if I repeatedly shift the array by $1$ to the right and add it to itself I get the answer:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

--------------------------------------------

[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

      [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

--------------------------------------------

[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

         [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

--------------------------------------------

[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

            [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

--------------------------------------------

[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

This translates to:

$1 + x^1 + x^2 + 2x^3 + 2x^4 + 2x^5 + 2x^6 + 2x^7 + x^8 + x^9 + x^{10}$

I see the mechanism, but how exactly does this work? And is it specific to this series?

(For the record, I googled this a lot but to be honest, I do not know how to put it in words exactly.)

Comment: It's probably using that $\,P_k(x)=(1+x^k)P_{k-1}(x) = P_{k-1}(x) + x^k P_{k-1}(x)\,$. Note that multiplication by $x^k$ counts as an array shift.

Comment: # $\color{blue}{p_k(x) = p_{k-1} + x^kp_{k-1}}$ has helped me solve [3B1B-Olympiad Level Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOXCLR3Wric). However, [my solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363800/how-does-this-algorithm-that-multiplies-1-x1-x21-x31-x4/4363954#4363954), as detailed in my post, has an issue in that it cannot handle large numbers. To mitigate this issue, I used `gmpy2.mpz`. Despite this, I have encountered max_recursion in the [code](https://linkode.org/#t6E1nyQd8ZQ223qOGeLG14)., if there are any suggestions that you can offer, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are interested in finding the coefficient for [infinite products](https://linkode.org/#EWUNrkBtV9MA1Hr6uE7n45) as there in your question title $$\prod_{k\ge1}(1+x^k) = (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)(1+x^4)....$$ then this is the generating function for something very interesting thing coming from number theory or should I say [Theory of Partitions of Integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))

$$\sum_{n\ge0}q(n)x^n  = \prod_{k\ge1}(1+x^k)$$
Where $q(n)$ you can find from [$\text{Integer sequences: }A000009$](https://oeis.org/A000009)

As commented by @dxiv $\color{blue}{p_k(x) = p_{k-1} + x^kp_{k-1}}$

```
import numpy as np
def p(k):
    if k == 1:
        return np.array([1, 1])
    else:
        q = p(k-1)
        return add(q, np.append(np.zeros(k, int), q))

    
def add(u, v):
    u = np.append(u, np.zeros(len(v)- len(u), int))
    return np.add(u, v)
print(p(int(input())))
```